# How to find the users default browser on Mac

Tags: java, macos

In the program I'm creating i need to know what browser the user is using. I don't need to open it just determine what it is. I know i can do this on windows with the registry but I have no clue about mac. I have tried looking at the `Desktop.getDesktop()` function but it only allows me to open the browser.

Comment: **Why** do you need to find out what it is without opening it?

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: Do any of the answers over here still work? http://superuser.com/questions/613362/discover-default-browser-programmatically-on-mac

Comment: Yeah these commands no longer work in the latest version of OS X